# Order of execution on stream listeners?

Tags: dart

Is there a way to enforce the order of execution for a broadcast stream with multiple listeners where order of execution matters?

```
  StreamSubscription<T> listen(void onData(T event)?,
      {Function? onError, void onDone()?, bool? cancelOnError});
```

The abstract definition doesn't seem to support it. I was looking for perhaps something like a 'priority' parameter to specify the order of operation.

For example, right now I have a UserController that notify its listeners to do something when the user changes. However, some of the listeners need to be prioritised, but they need to be in their own separate class. Example code:

```
class UserController{
  Stream user;
}

class IndependentControllerA {
//...

  userController.user.listen((){
    // This needs to be carried out first before everything else
  }

//...
}

class IndependentControllerB {
  userController.user.listen((){
    // This needs to be carried out before A
  }
}
```

What I have thought to overcome this is for UserController to instead register a list of its own Future callbacks that can be awaited in order. See example:

```
class UserController {
  List<Future Function()> callbacks;
  
  void changeUser() async {
    callbacks.forEach((callback) => await callback());
  }
}

class IndependentControllerA {
  //...
  userController.callbacks.add(() => print('Do first thing'));
  //...
}

class IndependentControllerB {
  //...
  userController.callbacks.add(() => print('Do second thing'));
  //...
}
```

However, I feel that this is not very elegant, if there is a better innate way to do this already with stream. Is there?

Answer (score 0):

The order that listeners are notified in is definitely not something Dart promises. In practice, it's likely to be ordered in some way depending on the order the listeners were added, but it's not a guarantee, and it might change at any time. (Not really, there's definitely badly written code which depends on the ordering and will break if the ordering changes, but that just means there'll have to be a good reason for the change, not that it can't happen).

I'd write my own "prioritizer" if I had such a specific need. Something like what you have started here. Knowing the specific requirements you have might make it much simpler than making a completely general solution.